# Commenting on a 4 year old question to ask for its current validity?

Tags: discussion, comments, old-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092754/using-greasemonkey-and-jquery-to-intercept-json-ajax-data-from-a-page-and-proce) received a good answer, 4 years ago. Would it be acceptable to comment on the answer asking whether or not it's still applicable or whether a slightly modification of their given method would suffice? This would alert the person who answered the question without starting a new unnecessary question.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, that's what comments are for.

> Use comments to ask for clarification or add more information.

Comment: So the age of the answer is irrelevant?

Comment: Yes. It might not be as helpful if OP is long gone, but future visitors can still answer.

Comment: It's been 17 minutes since this was last active. Is the answer still relevant?

Comment: @edge You can always tell if the OP is still active by looking at his profile.